# Backbone.Marionette: Router Not Routing Correctly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette, backbone-routing

So I have a button in my landing page view that, when clicked, should route my user to the register URL, initiate my `register` function in my router, and render the register view. The only problem is that it seems to be routing incorrectly.

Here's my landing-page view:

```
template = require './templates/landing'
app = require '../application'

module.exports = class LandingView extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    id: 'landing-view'
    template: template

    events:
        'click .splash .get-started': 'route_register'

    route_register: (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log 'button clicked'
        app.router.navigate('/register', {trigger: true})
```

and here's my router:

```
application = require('application')
HomeView = require('views/HomeView')
LandingView = require('views/LandingView')
RegisterView = require('views/RegisterView')

module.exports = class Router extends Backbone.Router

    routes:
        '': 'landing'
        '/home': 'home'
        '/register': 'register'

    landing: =>
        console.log 'in router: landing'
        lv = new LandingView()
        application.layout.content.show(lv)

    home: =>
        console.log 'in router: home'
        hv = new HomeView()
        application.layout.content.show(hv)

    register: =>
        console.log 'in router: register'
        rv = new RegisterView()
        application.layout.content.show(rv)
```

In my landing-page view, when the button is clicked, I get the console.log in chrome tools. But I never get the console.logs from the router. This led me to believe that my router was instantiated incorrectly but here's how I do it:

```
class Application extends Backbone.Marionette.Application
    initialize: =>

        @on("initialize:after", (options) =>
            Backbone.history.start();
            # Freeze the object
            Object.freeze? this
        )

        @addInitializer( (options) =>
            # Instantiate the main layout
            AppLayout = require 'views/AppLayout'
            @layout = new AppLayout()
            @layout.render()
        )

        @addInitializer((options) =>
            # Instantiate the router
            Router = require 'lib/router'
            @router = new Router()
        )
```

Also, the address chanages in the URL bar, for example, when I click the landing-page button  the URL changes from `localhost:3000` to `localhost:3000/register`, yet I don't get the console.log in the router and the page doesn't render.

Could anyone help me pin down this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An hour of debugging and it's.... a dumb typo error.

If you include a `/` in front of your `routes` object in `Backbone.Router` **routing will not work correctly.** I removed the forward slashes and everything works.

Incorrect routes:

```
routes:
    '/': 'landing'
    '/home': 'home'
    '/register': 'register'
```

Correct routes:

```
routes:
    '': 'landing'
    'home': 'home'
    'register': 'register'
```